# Iterate a function that generates dependent dropdowns in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, iteration, dropdown

I wrote a code to create a dependent dropdown in cell S9 of my file called "SLEEPING ASSETS List - March". This dropdown depends on R9 value. My dropdowns choices are in a file called "DATA".
I'm trying to create the same thing but on the range S9:S (not only in the cell S9).
Every dropdown in column S needs to be dependent of the chosen value in the column R of the same row.
It seems that my apps script skills are limited & that's why your help will be precious for me.

Here is the code I wrote to create the dependent dropdown in cell S9:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var actionValue = e.value;
  var returnValues = [];
  
  if(sheetName == 'SLEEPING ASSETS List - March' && column == 18 && row == 9 )
  {
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
    var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SLEEPING ASSETS List - March");
    
    //GET SQL STATEMENT
    var lastRowData = dataSheet.getLastRow();    
    for(var i = 2; i <= lastRowData; i++)
    {
     if(actionValue == dataSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
     {
       returnValues.push(dataSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());      
     }
    }
    
    mainSheet.getRange('S9').clear();
    var dropdown = mainSheet.getRange('S9');
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(returnValues).build();
    dropdown.setDataValidation(rule);

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: How can I create a dependent dropdown in each cell of S9:S based on the value in the column R chosen by the user ?

Comment: For example : User choose "ACTION 1" in R10, I want the dropdown in S10 to show him the choices dependent of the "ACTION 1". If another user choose "ACTION 2" In R11, I want the dropdown in S11 to show him the choices dependent of the "ACTION 2". Etc...

Comment: Your solution may not be working because onEdit is a simple trigger and cannot perform operation that require permission.  Try testing your code without using onEdit at first or switch to installable onEdit trigger.  Rename your function if you move to an installable trigger.

Comment: Keep in mind that simple triggers must complete in 30 seconds

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer ! I'll try with an installable onEdit trigger.

Comment: It's not clear to how to create drops based upon a single phrase like Action 1 or Action 2.  I would have expected a list or a range.